# Компиляция и запуск c++ в VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Питаюсь запустить c++ в VS Code

`tasks.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "command": "g++",
  "args": ["-g","-std=c++11","${file}","-o","${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasename}.exe"],
  "problemMatcher": {
      "owner": "cpp",
      "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
      "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
          "file": 1,
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "severity": 4,
          "message": 5
      }
  }
}
```

`launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",                
          "type": "cppdbg",                         
          "request": "launch",                        
          "targetArchitecture": "x86",                
          "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasename}.exe",                 
          "miDebuggerPath":"C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe", 
          "args": [],     
          "stopAtEntry": false,                  
          "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",                  
          "externalConsole": true,                  
          "preLaunchTask": "g++"　　                  
          }
  ]
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/*",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/tr1",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/include",
                "C:/MinGW/include"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/tr1",
                    "C:/MinGW/mingw32/include"
                ]
            },
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

При попытке сборки получаю такое сообщение в терминале: *Процесс терминала завершен с кодом выхода: 1*

Вот сам код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Где находится g++.exe, и перечисленна ли эта папка в PATH?

Comment: @Chorkov, он находиться по такому пути C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe, и все библот